# SQL Performance - Views vs Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a statement that takes around 15 seconds to load, which is way too long.. I would like to see what is the best way to 'Cache' this data into the memory.  Would I use somekind of View or Stored Procedure for this?  I'm aware i can use triggers and another table, but I would like to avoid that at all costs, there is quite a bit of memory to spare.

Any suggestions?

Comment: View and SP would perform **the same query**. So obviously they are not the solution in this case (at least following what you've said)

Comment: I suggest you a view called from stored procedure. View is cached automatically by SQL Server and stored procedure is pre-compiled (more fast). This two things togheter can help you with performance improvements. (Excuse for my bad english).

Comment: Don't you have to do something special to the View?  Like cluster or something, i'm new.

Comment: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/59/posts/13696/interview-question-difference-between-views-and-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: "I suggest you a view called from stored procedure." --- omg, please say it is a joke

Comment: Views don't get cached. Not even their execution plans.

Comment: So which is it, Views get Cached or no?

Comment: @Zee Tee: none of them would improve the performance of a query automagically. If query is slow - improve it and the schema

Comment: @RoBYCoNTe: What do you mean that a view is cached automatically?

Comment: If you can index the view, it can go faster.

Comment: Views, like stored procedure, once executed first time, are optimized and their execution plan is stored in cache in case they need to be reused. I dont know if is possible in your case but you can see this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx I hope it can help

Comment: @Gabe I think indexing is what i'm looking for.

Comment: sorry, I badly explained

Comment: In any case, giving my answer, I assumed that any other check to improve the query has already been made.

Comment: @RoBYCoNTe, a view's execution plan cannot get cached because you cannot execute a view! The plan for the query using that view gets cached. Many different queries might use the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out indexed views (usually called materialized views in other RDBMS).

Answer (score 0):

Do you know why your query is taking 15 seconds to run? Is the query working off the correct indexes? As others have mentioned, running the same query within a stored procedure is going to produce the same performance as the execution plan will be the same.

You might get better mileage out of using the SQL Query Optimizer and optimizing out the bottlenecks in your query. [This](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/the-sql-server-query-optimizer/) is a good article on using the SQL Query Optimizer.

Comment: so an indexed view will not be quicker than a standard sp?  The indexes on the columns would need to be optimized regardless, but i'm talking about in general.

Comment: @ZeeTee this is like asking if a motorcycle is faster than a plane. While an indexed view might speed up an individual query, it depends on a lot of factors and might not be the right answer anyway (due to the maintenance costs incurred by all DML operations). You're asking a very broad question and there is no magic generic answer, except you seem to think for some reason that the only things you can do to speed up a query are create a view or create a stored procedure, and the answer is no. They are 2 different object types with different purposes, and IMHO you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: PS re: the motorcycle vs. plane comment, I bet once the plane has landed, the motorcycle can beat it from the runway to the gate.

Answer (score -2):

IT ALL DEPEND ON YOU, MAKE SURE TO CHECK UR EXECUTION PLAIN AND TRY TO AFFORD TOO MUCH OF SCAN, U WILL GET BETTER PERFROMANCE. I HOPE THIS HELP